# Proper indexing for SELECT with OR condition

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7

I want to get all the rows where sub string is in the first/last name.
Then I want to order it by the exact match first and limit to 5 (pagination basically)
Query works well until the table is getting huge, so I wonder if I can better tune it.

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, (first_name='nir' OR last_name='nir') exact_match
FROM users
WHERE first_name like '%nir%'
      OR last_name like '%nir%'
Order by exact_match desc, last_name, first_name 
limit 5 offset 0;

create table users( 
id int , 
first_name varchar(100), 
last_name varchar(100), 
primary key(id), 
key first_name(first_name),
key last_name(last_name));

insert into users values(1,'anir','asd');
insert into users values(2,'ansir','asnird');
insert into users values(3,'nir','asnird');
insert into users values(4,'nixr','nir');
insert into users values(5,'nsixr','nsir');
```

Comment: You can't index for a `LIKE` with wildcard prefix anyway `%nir%`, only for non-prefixed `nir%` or exact match `nir`

Comment: As the others are saying, you cannot get performance from searching on substrings.  Rethink the UI's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to improve this query very much because of the prefix wildcard.

Without any changes, the query execution plan shows it will not make use of your indexes:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, first_name, last_name, (first_name='nir' OR last_name='nir') exact_match 
FROM users 
WHERE first_name like '%nir%' OR last_name like '%nir%' 
ORDER BY exact_match desc, last_name, first_name  
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
     filtered: 36.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

You can improve it a little bit by creating a compound index:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX idx_names (first_name, last_name);
```

Which gives the following query execution plan:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx_names
      key_len: 206
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
     filtered: 36.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

As you can see, this will make use of the compound index, However, if I understand correctly, it only does so after first having filtered the table  using the where condition.

Comment: Assuming there are more columns in the table, this "covering" index ("Using index") is better only because the INDEX's BTree is smaller than the data's BTree.  It still requires a full scan.

Answer (score 0):

How about a compromise -- assume that the user is asking about the *beginning* of either the first or last name.  This will work efficiently for a "huge" table:

```
( SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM tbl
    WHERE first_name LIKE 'nir%' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM tbl
    WHERE last_name LIKE 'nir%' )
ORDER BY (first_name = 'nir' OR last_name = 'nir') DESC,
    last_name,
    first_name
LIMIT 5, 0
```

And toss the two indexes you have, replacing them by two composite indexes:

```
INDEX(last_name, first_name, id),
INDEX(first_name, last_name, id)
```

Another approach -- Do the above; if you don't get 5 names, then go back to your slower query.  This will help the overall performance of the system.  But it will lead to individual searches being either fast (my query) or slow (needing both queries).

Comment: Problem is, this does not cover the scenario, `nir` is part-of or in-middle-of the string.